# Stored procedure count number of rows with id numbers in the count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get count total numbers of claims with the ID.

```
SELECT   
    InsuranceId,Name,
    COUNT(claimid) AS TotalPendingClaims
FROM 
    Claim 
GROUP BY
    InsuranceId
```

This is my query, but I want to get `claimid` also which is counted in the above query. I need column  `claimIds=(1,2,4,5)`

Expected result:

```
InsuranceId  Name TotalPendingClaims  ClaimIds
-----------------------------------------------
1            Med     2                  23,24
2            TX      1                   55
3            TED     3                  44,45,46
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: please check my question again i added expected result also

Comment: ClaimIds here is string column with samples value like 23,24 or 55 ?

Comment: I guess this answer is similar to what you want to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: no claimIds is new column which get the claimId which are Group by InsuranceId.

Comment: Your query is wrong or incomplete. When you group by InsuranceId, you cannot select name, PayerID837. One more thing, can you post table structure of Claim table ?

Comment: Kindly share sample data from which you want to obtain the desired result mentioned in question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT InsuranceId, name, COUNT(*) TotalPendingClaims, 
ClaimIds = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, claimid)
           FROM  dbo.Claim c2
           WHERE c1.InsuranceId = c2.InsuranceId AND c1.name = c2.name
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM claim c1
GROUP BY InsuranceId, name
ORDER BY InsuranceId, name
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
    SELECT   
        InsuranceId
        , count(claimid) as TotalPendingClaims
        , claimids = STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(claimid as varchar(255)) FROM Claim B WHERE B.InsuranceId = A.InsuranceId FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
            From Claim A
            Group by InsuranceId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following query in which stuff concatenates the claim ID's and count can be calculated seperately

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.InsuranceId ,
    STUFF((Select ','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), claimid) FROM #TEMP_INSURANCE T1 
WHERE T1.InsuranceId=T2.InsuranceId FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')  AS ClaimID,
    Cnt
FROM #TEMP_INSURANCE t2 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT InsuranceId,COUNT(claimid) Cnt FROM #TEMP_INSURANCE GROUP BY InsuranceId)T ON t.InsuranceId = t2.InsuranceId
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of my Problem is :

```
--changes addded by Ali Imran 12/13/2017 get also the claim number

claimid=stuff
(
 ( select distinct','+cast(c1.claimid as varchar(max))
  from #Claim c1 where
  c1.insuranceid=ins.insuranceid

  for xml path('')
  ),1,1,''
),

--Changes ended by Ali Imran
```